# Improving the following code for MIPS assembly language

Tags: c, mips

The purpose of the my program is to sort numbers based on the user input. Everything works perfectly, until user wants to input more than 6 data (inp = 5) and I am not sure why is it happening. Can you review it and let me know the reason behind it?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int size =0;

void ascSort(int *a, int size, int temp) {
  for(int i=1; i< size; i++){
      for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
        if(a[j-1]>a[j]){
          temp = a[j-1];
          a[j-1] = a[j];
          a[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
}

void descSort(int *a, int size, int temp) {
  for(int i=1; i< size; i++){
      for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
        if(a[j-1]<a[j]){
          temp = a[j-1];
          a[j-1] = a[j];
          a[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
}
int main(){
  char inpChar, isContinue='y';
  int inp, temp=0;
  int * a = malloc(0 * sizeof(*a));

  do {
    printf("How many numbers would you like to sort?\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &inp);
    size = inp;

    printf("%d\n", size);

    a = realloc(a, size * sizeof(*a));

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      //Below, I am printing 'size' for debugging purposes
        printf("Type %d more numbers to sort ---- '%d'\n", inp, size);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        inp--;
    }
    printf("Please input a for ascending order and d for descending order\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf(" %c", &inpChar);

    switch (inpChar) {
      case 'a':
        ascSort(a, size, temp);
        break;
      case 'd':
        descSort(a, size, temp);
        break;
      default: printf("Invalid character\n");
    }

    printf("Sorted Array: \n" );
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    printf("Do you want to repeat? Type y/n\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf(" %c", &isContinue);
  } while(isContinue != 'n');

}
```

After "inp" value increases to 6, "inp" value shows garbage value which is not expected at all.

**Note** Code is updated and working now. Now, my question is how to improve this code so that I can transform this code to MIPS assembly language? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot declare an array with a variable number of elements like that. You need to dynamically allocate the space using `malloc()` and a pointer.

Comment: ok. I will try to fix using malloc(). And, is there anything that you think I may be missing out?

Comment: `size` is zero, so you have an array of 0 elements in `int a[size];` Not even sure if the standard allows for that. Even if it does, an array with 0 elements is useless.

Comment: thanks @torstenvl it works now. I actually need it to work as I will have to transform this code for MIPS register. So, I will appreciate if you can let me know what I should optimize in my code. Thanks.